# Select and pair leftmost and rightmost elements in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array e.g `[0,1,2,3,4,5]` the length will always be even.

How do I select and pair starting from the leftmost and rightmost elements all the way to the center position?

In the above array it should result `[[0,5],[1,4],[2,3]]`

I have tried this so far... [here](https://flems.io/#0=N4IgZglgNgpgziAXAbVAOwIYFsZJAOgCsEAaEAYwHs0AXGWvKtOGgAgwCcPWBeV5AAwkAjCQBMJAMwkALCQCsAXQA6aVUxasO8AK5Q2fZCrQa2AB0pw4EAEawAshhrkAFvF7su+WGgDmNF1YAelYxVVUwSm4AClg2AA8PAQBuVkSAHlYLK1sHJ1d4VPiAamKASlZgVVYtXX18Mx04F2jkTg5keMUSTw7273p-QIBaNNZR4UVFMtUAX3CTajhKWG9KX2jtOD0aMpAyOBhYchoIJbxJRHkQWcVZoA)

```
const arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5]

const result = []
const possibleMatches = arr.length / 2

for (let x = 0; x < possibleMatches; x++) {
  result.push([arr[x], arr[arr.length - x - 1]])
}

console.log(result)
//[ [ 0, 5 ], [ 1, 4 ], [ 2, 3 ] ]
```

However, I think they must be better approach than for loop? like using one line arrow function e.t.c?

Comment: `[...arr].reduceRight((acc,_,__, src) => (acc.push([src.shift(), src.pop()]), acc), [])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the array in half (with [`Array.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)), then [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the array and use the same logic as you did in your `for` loop to get the item on the "right" side:

```js
const arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

const result = arr.splice(0, arr.length / 2).map((e, i) => [e, arr[arr.length - i - 1]])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Since splice mutates the original array so I have added `arr.slice(0)` at the beggining.

Answer (score 1):

take the second half of the array, flip it and merge it with the first half.

here's the one liner.

```js
const arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5]

const result = arr.slice(arr.length / 2 * -1).reverse().map((element, index) => [arr[index],element])
const possibleMatches = arr.length / 2

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.from()` to create an array with half the size of the original, and take the values from the start and end of the original array:

```js
const arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5]

const result = Array.from(
  { length: Math.ceil(arr.length / 2) },
  (_, i) => [arr[i], arr[arr.length - 1 - i]]
)

console.log(result)
```

You can use [`Array.at()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at) (if supported) to reduce the need for `length` calculations:

```js
const arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5]

const result = Array.from(
  { length: Math.ceil(arr.length / 2) },
  (_, i) => [arr.at(i), arr.at(-i-1)]
)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Given it's guaranteed that input array length is always even, using `Math.ceil()` seems to be overkill. However, if input array happens to be of odd length, the result wouldn't look _valid_ anyways.

Comment: Might be, but since the user haven't actually addressed this possibility, I prefer the better safe than sorry approach.

Comment: *> ...haven't actually addressed this possibility..* Isn't that what they stated explicitly in the very first sentence of the question body?

Comment: Does SO only works for the single user that asked the question? Address as in "what would happen if the array's length was odd".

Answer (score 1):

Using a simple `for` loop iterating from both ends

```js
const arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

let res = [],
  i = 0,
  j = arr.length - 1;
  
for (; i < j; i++, j--) {
  res.push([arr[i], arr[j]]);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

or `while`

```js
const arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

const result = [];

while (arr.length > 1) {
  result.push([arr.shift(), arr.pop()]);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```